# Trying to get an array of images to work on Onclick

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

```
//This is the Bullet Class. Here All I need is the Y position (because the Bullet is going only Y. The image which is in my drawable hdpi folder contains the image of my bullet.



public class Bulletbun extends GameObject  {

private int deltaY;


private android.media.Image img;


public Bulletbun(final int xPos, final int yPos, final Image img){


this.img= img;
this.xPos=xPos;
this.yPos=yPos;

}
public Bulletbun(float f, int i, int j, String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage (img, xPos, yPos, null);

}

@Override
void update() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}



}
}
```

// Trying to make it fire from here... This is my OnClick. What I want is When I touch the button I made, an Image would shoot out on the Y position of the screen. Also If I were to hit it multiple time it would shoot more than one (5). But also destroy the ones that are off-screen to save memory.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {    //+sound
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  //+sound


            Bulletbun Bulletbunny= new Bulletbun(bunbutt.getX()+20, 4,4,      "images/air_bunny.png");



            if (barrelblast != 0)
                sp.play(barrelblast, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);  //+sound

            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(90);


            smoke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                Handler delayedAction = new Handler();

                delayedAction.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                smoke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


     //This is my GameObject Class 

package com.ramy.fallingbarrels;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics;

import android.media.Image;

public abstract class GameObject {

protected Image img;
protected int xPos;
protected int yPos;

abstract void draw (Graphics g);

abstract void update();






public Image getImg() {
    return img;
}
public void setImg(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
}
public int getxPos() {
    return xPos;
}
public void setxPos(int xPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
}
public int getYpos() {
    return yPos;
}
public void setYpos(int ypos) {
    this.yPos = ypos;
}
```

//I was trying to follow a tutorial. If I'm doing something wrong here please tell me. Also if there's a better way to do what I described please tell me.

Comment: 1. Please fix your formatting. 2. Outline what the problem is clearly.

Comment: I made some changes added more detail and described my problem in more detail.

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong constructor of your `Bulletbun` class. You're calling the `public Bulletbun(float f, int i, int j, String string)` constructor which isn't implemented.
Also a bit of advice: you're probably starting out with a bit too hard tutorial. Read and learn the basics about Android (or programming for that matter) before you turn to the more advanced stuff like games. Just a friendly advice :-)